# Как исправить ошибку транспонирования аккордов?

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток!

Код транспонирует аккорды, т.е. уменьшает/увеличивает тональность.
Всё работает вроде хорошо, но после изменения тональности(уменьш./увелич.) несколько раз, появляется ошибка.

Ошибку я никак не могу понять.
Функция `getChords(list)` возвращает массив строк *(пример: Amas77, Gbsus4, F#)* из тегов.

Переменная `searchReg` -- это массив найденных аккордов *(Am, Gb, F#)* в строке `getChords(list)`, из примера выше.

А `option` -- массив нескольких аккордов в строке (пример: **Gb**/**F#**, **Fm**asu/**Am**, результат: `['Gb', 'F#'], ['Fm', 'Am']`)
После нескольких манипуляций с тональностью ошибка, ошибка `Cannot read property 'option.length' of null`

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку эту!**

Спасибо!

Вот реализация:

```js
/*
 *  [1Tone.getchords(list) -- возвращает массив тегов
 *  list -- список элементов/тегов с аккордами
 *
 *  [2]Tone.getChangeTonality(direction) -- возвращает массив измененных акккордов[1]
 *  direction -- false/true. Уменьшение/увеличение
 *
 *  Tone.render(list, direct) -- отрисовка на странице
 */

let ListChords = $('.chord');

const Tone = (function() {
  const KeyList = [{
      /*halfFrom/To -- изменения на полтона, 0.5*/
      halfFrom: ['A', 'Ab', 'Bb', 'A#', 'Am', 'Abm', 'A#m', 'A', 'Am'],
      halfTo: ['Bb', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'Bm', 'Am', 'Bm', 'A#', 'A#m'],
      from: ['A', 'Ab', 'A#', 'Am', 'Abm', 'A#m'],
      to: ['B', 'Bb', 'C', 'Bm', 'Bbm', 'Cm'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['B', 'Bm', 'Bbm'],
      halfTo: ['C', 'Cm', 'Bm'],
      from: ['B', 'Bb', 'Bm', 'Bbm'],
      to: ['C#', 'C', 'C#m', 'Cm'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['C', 'C#', 'Cm', 'C#m'],
      halfTo: ['C#', 'D', 'C#m', 'Dm'],
      from: ['C', 'C#', 'Cm', 'C#m'],
      to: ['D', 'Eb', 'Dm', 'E#m'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['Eb', 'D', 'D', 'D#', 'Dm', 'D#m', 'Dm'],
      halfTo: ['E', 'D#', 'Eb', 'E', 'Ebm', 'Em', 'D#m'],
      from: ['D', 'D#', 'Dm', 'D#m'],
      to: ['E', 'F', 'Em', 'Fm'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['E', 'Em', 'Ebm'],
      halfTo: ['F', 'Fm', 'Em'],
      from: ['E', 'Eb', 'Em', 'Ebm'],
      to: ['F#', 'F', 'F#m', 'Fm'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['F', 'F#', 'Fm', 'F#m'],
      halfTo: ['F#', 'G', 'F#m', 'Gm'],
      from: ['F', 'F#', 'Fm', 'F#m'],
      to: ['G', 'Ab', 'Gm', 'Abm'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['G', 'Gb', 'G#', 'Gm', 'Gbm', 'G#m'],
      halfTo: ['Ab', 'E', 'A', 'Abm', 'Em', 'Am'],
      from: ['G', 'Gb', 'G#', 'Gm', 'Gbm', 'G#m'],
      to: ['A', 'F', 'Bb', 'Am', 'Fm', 'Bbm'],
    },
    {
      halfFrom: ['H', 'Bb', 'Bbm', 'Hm', 'Bm'],
      halfTo: ['C', 'H', 'Hm', 'Cm', 'Cm'],
      from: ['H', 'Hm'],
      to: ['C#', 'C#m'],
    },
  ];

  return {
    getChords: function(list) {
      let elements = [];

      for (let i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        elements[i] = list[i];
      }

      for (let i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        elements[i] = elements[i].textContent;
      }

      return elements;
    },

    getChangeTonality: function(direction) {
      let chords = this.getChords(ListChords),
        searchReg = [],
        option = [],
        result = [],
        tonStep = $('.block_button').data('step');

      for (let i = 0, len = chords.length; i < len; i++) {
        searchReg[i] = chords[i].match(/[A-H]m?b?#?/g);
      }

      let toChange = function(from, to, i) {
        for (let j = 0, lenJ = KeyList.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
          if (option.length > 1) {
            for (let l = 0, lenL = option.length; l < lenL; l++) {
              from.forEach((e, item) => {
                if (e === option[l]) {
                  result[i] = chords[i].replace(option[l], to[item]);
                }
              })
            }
          } else {
            from.forEach((e, item) => {
              if (e === option[0]) {
                result[i] = chords[i].replace(option[0], to[item]);
              }
            })
          }
        }
      }

      if (direction === true) {
        if (tonStep === 1) {
          for (let i = 0, lenI = chords.length; i < lenI; i++) {
            option = searchReg[i];

            for (let j = 0, lenJ = KeyList.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
              toChange(KeyList[j].from, KeyList[j].to, i);
            }
          }
        } else if (tonStep === 0.5) {
          for (let i = 0, lenI = chords.length; i < lenI; i++) {
            option = searchReg[i];

            for (let j = 0, lenJ = KeyList.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
              toChange(KeyList[j].halfFrom, KeyList[j].halfTo, i);
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (tonStep === 1) {
          for (let i = 0; i < chords.length; i++) {
            option = searchReg[i];

            for (let j = 0, lenJ = KeyList.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
              toChange(KeyList[j].to, KeyList[j].from, i);
            }
          }
        } else if (tonStep === 0.5) {
          for (let i = 0; i < chords.length; i++) {
            option = searchReg[i];

            for (let j = 0, lenJ = KeyList.length; j < lenJ; j++) {
              toChange(KeyList[j].halfTo, KeyList[j].halfFrom, i);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return result;
    },

    render: function(list, direct) {
      let elements = this.getChords(list);
      let chords = this.getChangeTonality(direct);

      list.each(e => {
        list[e].textContent = chords[e];
      })
    },
  }
}());

document.addEventListener('click', e => {

  if (e.target.dataset.tone === 'increase') {
    Tone.render(ListChords, true);
  } else if (e.target.dataset.tone === 'reduce') {
    Tone.render(ListChords, false);
  }
});
```

```css
.song {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.block {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.str {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.node {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.word {
  height: 18px;
}

.chord {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 5px;
}


/*btn act*/

.block_button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgrey;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-act:active {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div block="song-panel">
  <div class="block block__flex">
    <div class="block_button" data-tone="reduce" data-step="1">-</div>
    <div class="block_button" data-tone="increase" data-step="1">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="song">
  <div class="block en">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmadd9</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm6</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Большие</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">города,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Пустые</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word">поезда,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ни</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">берега,</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ни</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word">дна,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Всё</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">начинать</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D7</span>
      <span class="word">сначала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Холодная</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">война</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">И</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">время,</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">как</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word">вода,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Он</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">сошёл</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">с</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word">ума,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ты</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ничего</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D7</span>
      <span class="word">знала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word">ждёт.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">На</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">линии</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">огня</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Пустые</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">города,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">В</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">которых</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никогда</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ты</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">раньше</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">бывала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">И</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">рвутся</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">поезда</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">На</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">тонкие</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">слова,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Он</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">сошёл</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">с</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ума,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ты</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ничего</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">знала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ждёт.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block in">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Ebadd11+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fadd11</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Dadd9-</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Ebadd11+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmadd9</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm6</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word">ждёт.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто…</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block in">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm/F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                 <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Bbmaj</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Bb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D7</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">

                 <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Построил граф переходов при смене на тон. Меня смущает что для аккордов D#, Gb, D#m, Ebm, Gbm, H, G#, A#, G#m, A#m неизвестно куда переходить обратно. граф тут https://imgur.com/a/pfPo4xk

Comment: *Построил граф переходов при смене на тон.* Вообще-то сперва стоило разобраться в нотации... Построй кольцо переходов на полтона. Такой граф переходов - это одно кольцо (граф переходов на тон - это два кольца). Надо перейти на тон - переходи на два шага. В граф включи синонимы (до = си диез = ре дубль бемоль).

Comment: @coder675 точняк, алфавит то, не полный

Comment: У аккордов валом комбинаций (m sys dim etc). Нужно учесть смену главной буквы - суффикс же не меняется. Думаю так будет проще. Префикс от суффикса можно отделить регуляркой. Ну и если есть дробь - букву после дроби. Откройте несколько композиций на том же amdm.ru (кстати там есть и генератор аккордов)

Comment: `Fmasu/Am` - это ошибка. Через дробь пишется басовая нота, а не аккорд. Правильные варианты `Fmasu/A` `Fmasu/A#` `Fmasu/Ab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему очевидно, что при каких-то условиях `searchReg[i]` возвращает `null` в момент присвоения

```
option = searchReg[i];
```

Не знаю, насколько это будет правильно, но Вы можете написать:

```
option = searchReg[i] || [];
```

---

Вот что содержит массив `chords` после третьего нажатия на `"-"`:

```
["Gbm","Gbmadd9","G#m","G#m7","H","G#m6","Bb","Bb","Gbm","H","G#m7","Bb7","Gbm","H",
 "G#m7","Bb7","Gbm","Gbm+","Gbm","Gbm","Gbm+","","","","H","Hadd11+","","","Bb","Bb",
 "Bbadd9-","Bb","H","Hadd11+","","","Gbm","Gbmadd9","H","H","G#m7","G#m6","Bb","Bb",
 "","","","Gbm","Gbm+","Gbm","Gbm","Gbm+","Gbm","Fm/Gb","Gbm",
 "","","","","Gbmsus4","Gbm","","","","Bb","Bb7","Gbmsus4","Gbm"]
```

Видите пустые строчки? Они и дают `null`-ы в `searchReg`.

Comment: Да, действительно решает проблему. Надо было по другому задать вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал попроще просто списком тональностей. Но здесь опять же не учитывается тональность песни и сложные аккорды вроде Gm/F не совсем ясно как транспонировать.

```js
/*
 *  [1]Tone.getchords(list) -- возвращает массив строк с аккордами
 *  list -- список элементов/тегов с аккордами
 *  [2] findKey(key) -- возвращает номер аккорда(key) в списке KeyList 0-11
 *  [2]Tone.getChangeTonality(chords,step) -- возвращает массив измененных акккордов[1]
 * chords -- массив строк с аккордами
 * step -- изменение тона, минимальный шаг 0.5. Допустимые значения ±0.5, ±1, ±1.5, и т.д.
 *
 *  Tone.render(list, step) -- отрисовка на странице
 */

let ListChords = $('.chord');

const Tone = (function() {
  const KeyList = [
    ['C','B#','H#'],  //0
    ['Db','C#'],      //1
    ['D'],            //2
    ['Eb','D#'],      //3
    ['E','Fb'],       //4   
    ['F','E#'],       //5
    ['Gb','F#'],      //6
    ['G'],            //7
    ['Ab','G#'],      //8
    ['A'],            //9
    ['Bb','Hb','A#'], //10
    ['B','H'],        //11
  ];

  return {
    getChords: function(list) {
      let elements = [];

      for (let i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        elements[i] = list[i];
      }

      for (let i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        elements[i] = elements[i].textContent;
      }

      return elements;
    },

    findKey: function(key) {
      for (let i = 0; i < KeyList.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < KeyList[i].length; j++) {
          if (KeyList[i][j] == key) {
            return i;
          }
        }
      }
      
    },
    
    getChangeTonality: function(chords, step) {
    let result = [],
        strchord = [],
        repkey = [];
      for (let i = 0, len = chords.length; i < len; i++) {
        strchord = chords[i].match(/[A-H]#?b?/g);
        result[i] = chords[i];

        for (let i2 = 0, len2 = strchord.length; i2 < len2; i2++) {
          repkey[i2] = KeyList[(this.findKey(strchord[i2]) + step + 12) % 12][0];
          result[i] = result[i].replace(strchord[i2], '{'+i2+'}');
        }
        for (let i2 = 0, len2 = strchord.length; i2 < len2; i2++) {
          result[i] = result[i].replace('{'+i2+'}',repkey[i2]);
        }
      }
    return result;
    },

    render: function(list, step) {
      let chords = this.getChords(list);
      let newchords = this.getChangeTonality(chords, Math.round(Number(step) * 2));
      list.each(e => {
        list[e].textContent = newchords[e];
      })
    }, 
  }
}());

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    Tone.render(ListChords, e.target.dataset.tonestep);
  }
);
```

```css
.song {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.block {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.str {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.node {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.word {
  height: 18px;
}

.chord {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 5px;
}


/*btn act*/

.block_button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgrey;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-act:active {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div block="song-panel">
  <div class="block block__flex">
    <div class="block_button" data-tonestep="-1">-</div>
    <div class="block_button" data-tonestep="1">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="song">
  <div class="block en">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmadd9</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm6</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Большие</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">города,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Пустые</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word">поезда,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ни</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">берега,</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ни</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word">дна,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Всё</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">начинать</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D7</span>
      <span class="word">сначала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Холодная</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">война</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">И</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">время,</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">как</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word">вода,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Он</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">сошёл</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">с</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word">ума,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ты</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ничего</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D7</span>
      <span class="word">знала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word">ждёт.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">На</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">линии</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">огня</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Пустые</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">города,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">В</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">которых</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никогда</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ты</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">раньше</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">бывала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block co">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">И</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">рвутся</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">поезда</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">На</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">тонкие</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">слова,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Он</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">сошёл</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">с</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ума,</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Ты</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ничего</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">знала.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">ждёт.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block in">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Ebadd11+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fadd11</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Dadd9-</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Ebadd11+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmadd9</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Eb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm7</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Cm6</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word">ждёт.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block ch">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word">Полковнику</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Не</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word">пишет.</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="word">Полковника</span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word">никто…</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block in">
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm+</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm/F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                 <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Fsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">F</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Bbmaj</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Bb</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">D7</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="str">
      <span class="node">
                    <span class="chord">Gmsus4</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="node">

                 <span class="chord">Gm</span>
      <span class="word"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас проще алгоритм и это очень здорово)